# Programmatically access module/filename in Factor?

Tags: module, filenames, factor-lang

The program name specified in command line usage, e.g. `"Usage: rot13.factor [OPTIONS]"`.

Erlang has a macro called `?FILE` to access the source code's own filename. Does Factor have something similar?

[Rosetta Code](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/ScriptName#Erlang)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Factor's command-line vocabulary has a word `script` which either returns the script name or `f` when Factor is in interpreted mode.

```
#! /usr/bin/env factor

USING: namespaces io command-line ;
IN: scriptname

: main ( -- ) script get print ;

MAIN: main
```

Example:

```
$ ./scriptname.factor 
Program: ./scriptname.factor

$ factor
( scratchpad ) USING: command-line ;
( scratchpad ) script get .
f
```